# Create icon to launch an app (iPhone/iPad)

Tags: ios, ipad

I saw few blog where we can create custom ios app that will launch another app using custom URL. My question is, is it possible to just have a icon on home page so when user clicks on it, this will launch actual app without creating another ios app?

Basically, we are trying to rebrand icon of salesforce1 app to create better user experience.

Thanks,
Tapan

Answer (score 0):

Technically it's entirely possible. I don't know if Apple would allow such an app on the app store however.

Answer (score 0):

mmmm... maybe what you can do is create a web page that explains the user that they need to add this web as a bookmark in their home ios desktop. so then when the user opens the web page that looks like an app, from safari you can open apps using javascript

that is what Crashlytics does:
http://lifehacker.com/5809338/add-web-site-bookmarks-to-your-iphones-homescreen

btw, Crashlytics is a release beta tool made by twitter:

Comment: From the ios home desktop, it will look exactly like an app

Comment: Thanks Ponja for quick response. do you know how to change icon for this shortcut?

Comment: I think it's the page favicon